# PageViewController crash setViewControllers

Tags: swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have PageViewController and I want to show viewControllerAtIndex here is my code:

```
let startingViewController: MyPages = self.viewControllerAtIndex(0, storyboard: self.storyboard!)!
let viewControllers: NSArray = [startingViewController]
pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers as [AnyObject], direction: .Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

but my app crash with `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'`

viewControllers is not empty on println I have `<My_App.MyPages: 0x7fcce9813e00>`
This happens in new beta 3 on 8.3 on beta 2 it works.

Link to Apple Dev Forums: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/264976

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works after update on Mac X OS